# ZF2 Annotation builded form not working - all fields excluded

Tags: php, forms, annotations, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2.3.1 ( PHP 5.4.21 )
I'm trying to build form using annotations, code i'm using is simple:

controller:

```php
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Entity\Test;
use DoctrineORMModule\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;
// ...
```

```php
$entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
/* @var $entityManager \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
$test = new Test();
$builder = new AnnotationBuilder($entityManager);
// for debugging purposes
$spec = $builder->getFormSpecification($test);
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($spec);
```

Application\Entity\Test looks like this:

```php
namespace Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * @Annotation\Name("this-works")
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 */
class Test{


/** 
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
*/
protected $id;


/** 
* 
* @ORM\Column(type="string") 
* @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
* @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":1, "max":25}})
* @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Regex", "options":{"pattern":"/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,24}$/"}})
* @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"text"})
* @Annotation\Options({"label":"Username:"})
* @Annotation\AllowEmpty(true)
*/  
protected $fullName;


}
```

Result i get is:

```
object(ArrayObject)#338 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private] => array(6) {
    ["name"] => string(4) "this-works"
    ["attributes"] => array(0) {
    }
    ["elements"] => array(0) {
    }
    ["fieldsets"] => array(0) {
    }
    ["hydrator"] => string(35) "Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty"
    ["input_filter"] => object(ArrayObject)#339 (1) {
      ["storage":"ArrayObject":private] => array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

form name anntation is working, but all fields get excluded.

I was trying to debug it, and i figured out that if I change Zend/Form/Annotation/AnnotationBuilder.php function checkForExclude from (note remove of callback )

```
protected function checkForExclude($annotations)
{    

    $results = $this->getEventManager()->trigger('checkForExclude', $this, array(
        'annotations' => $annotations,
    ), function ($r) { 
        return (true === $r);
    });

    return (bool) $results->last();
}
```

to

```
protected function checkForExclude($annotations)
{    

    $results = $this->getEventManager()->trigger('checkForExclude', $this, array(
        'annotations' => $annotations,
    ));

    return (bool) $results->last();
}
```

it is working properly ( fullName field is in form declaration ).

Am I doing something wrong or is it just bug in ZF2 ?
Trying to figure it out for few days now, and i'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I have, so far, is to remove ZendDeveloperTools from application.config.php when using annotated forms.

Known Bug: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6166

Comment: Please Note: This issue was closed during the ZF2 bug migration. It will need to be reopened if it still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something interfering with the EventManager's listener chain.

I get the same result if I have the ZendDeveloperTools module enabled, for example. You can verify this by checking the final result passed to the event's callback closure in Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:464

```
$listenerCallback = $listener->getCallback();
if ('checkForExclude' === $event) {
    var_dump($listenerCallback);
}
```

If the class of the callback is anything other than Zend\Form\Annotation\ElementAnnotationsListener, then the closure is not going to receive the correct result as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily you can keep ZendDeveloperTools! All you need is to change one property to false in your ZDT autoload file located on ApplicationPath/config/autoload/zdt.local.php:

```
    array('Events' => array('Enabled' = false, ...), ...)
```